# cmake architecture issue with several compiler/subdirectory

Tags: c, linux, cmake, embedded-linux

I am building a library for an embedded target with a cross-toolchain. To generate this library, I must create another binary before with my host compiler. This binary generates some headers for my library. I find everywhere that I cannot use two different compilers in the same `CMakeLists.txt` file. CMake was not designed to do that.

So I am trying to do this with a subdirectory and 2 `CMakeLists.txt`. I have a main `CMakeLists.txt` file building the library. There is a `add_subdirectory` call in this main `CMakeLists.txt` file to generate my binary in a separate cmake file. The problem is that I cannot tell my main Cmake to do the subdirectory build before the main one.

My problem in a very minimalist example:

```
[arthur ] ls
CMakeLists.txt  my_subdir  source.c
[arthur ] ls my_subdir/
CMakeLists.txt  main.c
```

The top cmake file:

```
[arthur ] cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

message("Invoke my_subdir/CMakeList.txt")
add_subdirectory (my_subdir)


set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
#set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_DEPENDS_DEBUG_MODE 1)

project(doing_test)

# Build the great library
set(MY_GREAT_LIBRARY_SOURCE source.c)

add_library(great_library STATIC ${MY_GREAT_LIBRARY_SOURCE})
target_include_directories(great_library PRIVATE PUBLIC ".")
set_target_properties(great_library PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME my_super_great_library)
```

the subdirectory cmake file:

```
[arthur ] cat my_subdir/CMakeLists.txt
project (coucou)

message("Building mysubdir sources...")

# add the executable
add_executable(my_needed_subbinary main.c)
```

Building:

```
[arthur ] mkdir build && cd build
[arthur ] cmake .. && cmake --build .
Invoke my_subdir/CMakeList.txt
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
Building mysubdir sources...
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build
/usr/bin/cmake -S/home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test -B/home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build/CMakeFiles /home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build'
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/great_library.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/great_library.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build'
cd /home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test /home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test /home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build /home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build /home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build/CMakeFiles/great_library.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target great_library
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build'
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/great_library.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/great_library.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build'
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/great_library.dir/source.c.o
/usr/bin/cc  -I/home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/.   -o CMakeFiles/great_library.dir/source.c.o   -c /home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/source.c
[ 50%] Linking C static library libmy_super_great_library.a
/usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/great_library.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/great_library.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/ar qc libmy_super_great_library.a  CMakeFiles/great_library.dir/source.c.o
/usr/bin/ranlib libmy_super_great_library.a
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build'
[ 50%] Built target great_library
/usr/bin/make -f my_subdir/CMakeFiles/my_needed_subbinary.dir/build.make my_subdir/CMakeFiles/my_needed_subbinary.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build'
Scanning dependencies of target my_needed_subbinary
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build'
/usr/bin/make -f my_subdir/CMakeFiles/my_needed_subbinary.dir/build.make my_subdir/CMakeFiles/my_needed_subbinary.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build'
[ 75%] Building C object my_subdir/CMakeFiles/my_needed_subbinary.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable my_needed_subbinary
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build'
[100%] Built target my_needed_subbinary
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/arthur/work/repository/cmake_test/build/CMakeFiles 0
```

This is a basic need, but I cannot resolve my issue. I want to build my `main.c` to generate my subdirectory binary before building the main library. We can see in the output that he is calling the `CMakeLists.txt` of the subdirectory first but without building it.

I tried to add `add_dependencies` command in the top cmake but without success.

```
add_dependencies(great_library my_subdir) -> don't know my_subdir project
add_dependencies(great_library coucou) -> don't know coucou  project
```

**Solution inspired from @KamilCuk. I also change some names to have a more understandable example**.

The top Cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(multiple_compiler_example)

# use cross toolchain for this project
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc")

# define the header that the intermediate binary is generated. The header are generated in header_autogenerated directory
set(MY_GENERATED_HEADER
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header_autogenerated/my_generated_header1.h"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header_autogenerated/my_generated_header2.h"
)

# Cmake command to build the binary which generater the header
# compile in build directory and generate output binary in bin directory
add_custom_command(
  COMMENT "Generate header generator binary"
  DEPENDS
    header_generator/header_generator.c
    header_generator/CMakeLists.txt
  OUTPUT
     ${MY_GENERATED_HEADER}
  COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    -B ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header_generator/build
    -S ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header_generator
    -D CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header_generator/bin
  COMMAND 
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    --build ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header_generator/build
)

# Cmake code to run header_generator before compiling the library to generate all header
add_custom_target(generate_parameter_header
  COMMAND ./header_generator
  DEPENDS ${MY_GENERATED_HEADER}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header_generator/bin
  COMMENT "run header_generator...")

# my great library
add_library(my_great_library 
     source_library1.c
     source_library2.c
     source_library3.c
     # List the needed dependencies. ONE BY ONE
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header_autogenerated/my_generated_header1.h
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/header_autogenerated/my_generated_header2.h
)
target_include_directories(my_great_library PUBLIC
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/header_autogenerated
   .
)
add_dependencies(my_great_library generate_parameter_header)
```

My subdirectory Cmake :

```
project (header_generator)

# always use the x86 host compiler
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "gcc")

message("Building the header generator...")

# add the executable
add_executable(header_generator header_generator.c)
target_include_directories(header_generator PUBLIC "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}" ".")
```

Comment: If you're combining 2 `CMakeLists.txt` files using  `add_subdirectory` results in a single cmake project, configuration (independent on the number of `project` commands. Every single binary in this project will use the same compiler. In your case I'd recommend providing a "bootstrap script" to setup&build build the dependencies you need placing the resulting binaries in a place where they can be found by your real project. You could use `execute_process` to do this during the configuration of the main project, but I wouldn't recommend doing this...

Comment: See also [ExternalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)

Comment: As instructed in [ask], can you please write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title? For more guidance, see [How do I write a good title?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/997587)

Comment: The way CMake works is to go over *all* `CMakeLists.txt`s to generate `Makefile`s (or whatever) from them. Then, `make` is called on the generated `Makefile`s and invokes whatever compiler command is in there. You hide this in your `cmake .. && cmake --build .`. There's no skipping back and forth between CMake and the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subproject that's a *completely* different cmake. So run a *completely* different cmake.

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(doing_test)
add_custom_command(
  COMMENT "generate the includes that I wanna"
  DEPENDS
    my_subdir/main.c
    my_subdir/CMakeLists.txt
  OUTPUT
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_subdir/genincludes/include1.h
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_subdir/genincludes/include2.h
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_subdir/genincludes/etc.h
  COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    -B ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_subdir
    -S ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_subdir
    -D CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_subdir/bin
  COMMAND 
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    --build ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_subdir
  COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_subdir/bin/my_needed_subbinary
    --outputdir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_subdir/genincludes
)
add_library(great_library 
     source.c
     # List the needed dependencies. ONE BY ONE
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_subdir/genincludes/include1.h
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_subdir/genincludes/include2.h
     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_subdir/genincludes/etc.h
)
target_include_directories(great_library PUBLIC
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/my_subdir/genincludes
   .
)
```

Comment: Hello KamilCuk. Not sure to understand the add_library command here with all headers one by one. There is already the target_include_directory command which is going to generate the -I to include all the headers. I have more than 1400 headers generated it will be great to not have to reference them one by one.  Is it to create the dependency between custom_command and the add_library ? But basically, the solution here is to call manually the subdir Cmake with a custom command from the top Cmake ?

Comment: `Is it to create the dependency between custom_command and the add_library ?` Yes. You can do like `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch master_dependency_file` after generating all files and create the dependency on that single file. `basically, the solution here is to call manually the subdir Cmake with a custom command from the top Cmake ?` Yes

Comment: IF this command is going to be run once and once only, use `execute_process` and run it at configuration time or wrap your cmake execution in some master script. It's hard to talk about some "unknown script" - please give more details. Research other projects - Zephyr generates _a lot_ of files during compilation. Your question was about calling CMake with separate compiler - yes, you _have to_ call a separate cmake. It's one cmake call per compiler. Separate compiler - separate cmake call with separate binary dir.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I have a working clean Cmake... Thank you. I also find some inspiration from this: https://gist.github.com/socantre/7ee63133a0a3a08f3990. I am going to update my question to add my solution inspired from your answer